# statemachine state is always returning the last state instead of initial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, state-machine, aasm

I am trying to use aasm `state machine` for going from one `state` to another. But the `issue` is that the `statemachine` is moving through all `states` without calling. Here is the code am using

```
include AASM

  aasm column: 'state' do
    state :pending, initial: true
    state :checked_in
    state :checked_out
    event :check_in do
      transitions from: :pending, to: :checked_in, guard: :verify_payment?
    end
    event :check_out do
      transitions from: :checked_in, to: :checked_out
    end
  end

  def verify_payment?
    self.payment_status=="SUCCESS"
  end
```

Here If I do `Booking.create` it returns with `checked_out` state even initially instead of the expected `pending`

Why its returning the `last` expected state instead of `initial` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I have two `database fields` called `check_in` and `check_out`. So `activerecord` will consider it as attribute methods and fire those events on creation.So the fix here is to change the `event` name to something different than that in the database

```
 include AASM

      aasm column: 'state' do
        state :pending, initial: true
        state :checked_in
        state :checked_out
        event :move_to_check_in do
          transitions from: :pending, to: :checked_in, guard: :verify_payment?
        end
        event :move_to_check_out do
          transitions from: :checked_in, to: :checked_out
        end
      end

      def verify_payment?
        self.payment_status=="SUCCESS"
      end
```